# How can one put together multiple arrays into one string?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having a hard time describing what I'm looking for.

If we pretend that we're pulling an array (I've used the .split to get user input data)
where each line represents a link.

How can I then add an anchor tagg to that link that I'm pulling?

I need to be able to put

```
< a href=" + thearray + ">anything< /a>.
```

The reason for this is that I'm dynamically creating a list.

I think that if I create two variables, one with this part

```
< a href="
```

one with the closing
and then call some sort of function that puts those two and the pulled array in between them until the list is complete.

**Does this make any sense?**

edit:
here's a link to the full code:
http://hem.bredband.net/noor/thecode.txt

Comment: Why would you want an array of links to show up as the href to an anchor tag? You may have a valid question, but I think you need to express it better before it will make sense.

Comment: the thing is, im not pulling in any links, im pulling in file links from the users pc e.g. c:\pictures\apic.jpg .. i'm asking the user to write a few links to pictures, seperating them with a newline.

My code right now does that good, it gets the user inputs and i can output it into a new textarea in new lines etc..

I need to be able to put <img src=" infront and an ending after each of those rows..

Comment: btw.. please don't laugh guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
for(var x=0;x<thearray.length;x++) {
   document.write '<a href=" + thearray[x] + ">anything</a>'
}
```

You just want to loop through the array elements, wrapping them in some HTML.

Comment: I think this might be it but i'm just to dumb to figure it out, this is where it should be put in:

var trt = document.createElement("div");
 trt.setAttribute("Id","slideshow1");
 trt.className="pics";

for(var i=0;x<lines.length;i++) {
trt.innerHTML = "<img src=' + lines[i] + '></img>";
}

this isn't working, is there a book i can read maybe to fully understand what i'm doing? thanks!

Comment: @Noor, inside your for loop you are *replacing* the innerHTML each time, not adding to it. You should use "+=" rather than "=".

Comment: I've used this now and i'm getting this output:

file:///C:/Users/Admin/Pictures/bild3.jpgC:/Users/Admin/Pictures/micke.jpg

the only problem right now is instead of creating 2 different <img src=.... it's creating 1 img element with both of my links as the source.

I'll edit the thread with a link to the full code

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want to have an array like

```
["http://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.stackoverflow.com"]
```

and you want to turn it into

```
"<a href='http://www.google.com'>anything</a>
<a href='http://www.yahoo.com'>anything</a>
<a href='http://www.stackoverflow.com'>anything</a>"
```

?

If so, you can just do

```
var myArray = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.stackoverflow.com"];
var result = "";
for (var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
   result += "<a href='" + myArray[i] + "'>anything</a>";
}
```

If not, thinking about "I want to start with X and end up with Y", with specific examples, might help you clarify your question.

Comment: This is what i've done now but i can't seem to get it right, i updated the thread with a link to what i'm using right now.. its not doing it ..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean something like this:

```
var tagStart = '<a href="',
    tagEnd = '">anything</a>',
    html = tagStart + thearray.join(tagEnd + tagStart) + tagEnd;
```

I would still suggest using a loop, though, since the code above will be unkind if `thearray` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think using map and then join is going to be more readable:

```
function makeLink(url)
{
   return "<a href=\"" + url + "\">anything</a>";
}
result = myArray.map(makeLink).join("\n");
```

More info about map is available at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_map.htm